# How gcloud can list projects without enabled Resource Manager API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using GCP's golang sdk and try to list projects via [cloudresourcemanager](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) service:

```golang
res, err := service.Projects.List().Context(ctx).Do()
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.WithStack(err)
}
```

and get the following error:

```
ERROR STACKTRACE: googleapi: Error 403: Cloud Resource Manager API has not been used in project [PROJECTID] before or it is disabled. 
Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/overview?project=[PROJECTID] then retry. 
If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., accessNotConfigured
```

So I can't list projects if at least one of them doesn't have Resource Manager API enabled (which is weird).

However, the following command via GCP CLI works fine and returns all projects (even those without Resource Manager API enabled):

```sh
gcloud projects list
```

I know the CLI is using Python SDK, so I [looked it up](https://github.com/googleapis/python-resource-manager/blob/master/google/cloud/resource_manager/client.py#L133) and the method also uses the same resource manager API:

```py
return page_iterator.HTTPIterator(
    client=self,
    api_request=self._connection.api_request,
    path="/projects",
    item_to_value=_item_to_project,
    items_key="projects",
    extra_params=extra_params,
)
```

How is that possible? Does it have something to do with the authetication method? I'm using authentication via oauth2 token for my golang sample. Is there a way for me to list projects the same way `gcloud` does?

Comment: What is the authentication method you are using? What is/are the role(s) that has/have that authentication method?

Comment: @SamuelRomero I use oauth2 with the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"

Comment: I tried to perfomr this same action, actually using the link you provided https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list, and I was able to get the projects I have. Have you tried using the "Try this API" in the shared link? Do you get the same error? If you can retrieve this information, it seems like it will be a better option to open a support case in order to they take a look at it.

Comment: @SamuelRomero the "Try this API" works for me too but it seems it uses a different authentication method - you can see that the curl command uses api key in the query even if you uncheck "API Key" in credentials. And the code example states clearly: "BEFORE RUNNING: If not already done, enable the Cloud Resource Manager API"

Comment: You are totally right, the code example says that the API must be enabled, nevertheless, if since the "try this API" works, it should work as there. On the other hand, the only two ways to list projects is using the gcloud command and the using the REST API, so there is no other option to do it. It could be a good idea to open an issue tracker https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers to ask for a  feature request about a similar operation to the gcloud command using REST

Comment: @odenwouldntbeoden I'm running into the same. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @Ted what was your solution? Cloud Resource Manager API?